# When running npx run:android

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-dev-client

I'm trying to migrate to Bare Workflow.
Because I need a library that is not available at the expo.
so I migrated. Before adding the library, the app worked normally, however, after following the manual linking steps and running the app on the Android device, I receive this output below.

library I installed.

```
https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer
```

`Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainActivity.java:19: error: package R does not exist setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); ^ C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainActivity.java:39: error: cannot find symbol return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate( ^ symbol:   variable BuildConfig location: class MainActivity C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainApplication.java:26: error: cannot find symbol return BuildConfig.DEBUG; ^ symbol: variable BuildConfig C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainApplication.java:45: error: cannot find symbol return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED; ^ symbol: variable BuildConfig C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainApplication.java:50: error: cannot find symbol return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED; ^ symbol: variable BuildConfig C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainApplication.java:63: error: cannot find symbol if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) { ^ symbol:   variable BuildConfig location: class MainApplication C:\\Projetos\\gsmaketTotem_old\\gsmarketTotem\\android\\app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\rcia\\gsmarkettotem\\MainApplication.java:63: error: illegal parenthesized expression if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) { ^ 7 errors` 
I can't find what to try